# What's the best way to store a huge array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

Say I wanted to create a Chrome extension that displays a random word every time it's loaded, with each random word having an equal chance of appearing. To get the random word, I would store an English dictionary as an array, generate a random number and retrieve the word at that index.

My question is: what is the best practice for storing and retrieving the data? Ideally, I'd want to minimize the memory consumption and retrieve in O(1) time.

Some options I've considered are:

1. Store the dictionary in a JSON file and parse it in background.js
2. Store the dictionary using an array literal at the head of the background.js file e.g.

   `var dict = [
     "apple",
     "banana", 
     "cat", 
      .... 
     /*thousands of lines of dictionary words in code*/
     "yak",
     "zebra"
   ]`
3. Store the dictionary using chrome.storage

I'm not all that familiar with JavaScript or Chrome extensions so I wonder what would be the best way to go about implementing this.

Comment: Retrieving is always `O(1)` ?!? And a json file sounds good.

Comment: I was under the assumption that JavaScript stores arrays as Hash Tables. So the retrieval time of an index would always be O(1) wouldn't it?

Comment: Nope. Arrays are stored as arrays. However array retrieval is O(1) too?!?

Comment: Getting an element from an Array is O(1), since you know the address of the first element and the size of each element. That's what they taught us at C programming classes at least.

Comment: Yes, array lookup is typically O(1) in most programming languages. I assumed it was the same in JS.

Comment: Does this extension need internet access, or it should be able to run even if user is not connected?

Comment: Let's say it should run even without internet access

Comment: Then I would start with adding 2 tables, with 20 words in each, where any combination would create a valid word, e.g. apple-pie, lemon-soda etc.. That would give you 440 words initially, then every time the extension loads, and you have internet access, get the word from an online resource, if not, get one from the buffer. Now, with that, you can easily see the users behavior and decide how big this buffer needs to be, and if needed, little by little swap/update that initial table with a new one/more words.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I should have specified: each dictionary word should have an equal chance of appearing - which is why I proposed using an array to hold a list of all dictionary words.

Comment: Well they have, just make these 20+20 words the first 20 and last 20 in the array, and then randomly pick 2 index values, one between 1-20, another between 21-40.

Comment: Btw, these words, do they have a special meaning for the user? ... if not, then why do you make it more complicated than it has to be.  I mean, if I were to download such extension and it would fill up my computer with meaningless words, it wouldn't stay for long.

Comment: No, no special meaning. They're literally any random dictionary word. I guess the core of my problem is in figuring out what the best way to store an entire dictionary would be, without the need for external resources. Is it better to store in a local JSON or to declare an array directly in the JavaScript file?

Comment: The core of your problem is _space_, and I just showed you how you can get 440 out of 40. Whether they are stored as JSON or Array will be less important, since both are Javascript objects. And to store a JSON local, you still need to load/parse it into an object to access the words.

Comment: Any solution you mentioned will work with a few megabytes of words. All routes are trivial to implement so just go ahead.